# Как очистить Navigation Stack

Tags: swift, view, controller, transition, navigationcontroller

При запуске приложения, View hierarchy основного (is Initial View Controller) контроллера выглядит так:
[image]
.

Однако после перехода на другой контроллер и возврата на основной, в навигационном стеке появляются UITransitionView.

Вот, что произойдет, если я много раз сделаю переход туда-обратно.
[image]

Тип переходов - modal. Пробовал Present modally - эффект тот же. Что это и как сделать так, чтобы мой навигационный стек не засорялся?

Обновлено: выяснилось, что контроллеры после перехода остаются в памяти, как будто их что то держит. Создал два пустых контроллера, на первом кнопка при нажатии на которую осуществляется переход. Итог - первый контроллер висит в памяти после перехода. Что его может держать?

Comment: похоже на утечку, что-то держит ваш контроллер и не дает ему зарелизиться. Напишите метод deinit  и посмотрите вызывается он или нет. Вероятнее всего его что-то держит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы переходите таким образом с 1 на 2, с 2 на 1, то они остаются. Чтобы при переходе уничтожились все предыдущие контроллеры, необходимо их очищать. Для проверки добавьте кнопку и по нажатию:

```
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!
    let previousController = window.rootViewController
    for element in window.subviews {
        element.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    window.rootViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SECONDVC")
    previousController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
        previousController?.view.removeFromSuperview() 
    })
}
```

Пример на [GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/HardWindowCleanForSO)

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы ответить на вопрос, связанный с Вашим решением данной проблемы? Мне необходимо при переходе на следующий VC передать определенные данные, но я не могу разобраться как. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926915/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-navigation-stack