# Возможно ли обнулить Navigation Stack?

Tags: swift, стек, uiviewcontroller

Пользуюсь методами `self.navigationController?.pushViewController()`, `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`.

Заметил, что чем больше мы переходим по ViewController'ам, тем больше VC находится в стеке(то есть при нажатии на клавишу Back в NavBar мы можем вернуться к самому первому VC). Возможно ли как нибудь обнулить данный стек?

UPD. Нашел решение, но не могу разобраться в нем.

```
let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!
        let prewController = window.rootViewController
        for element in window.subviews {
            element.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        window.rootViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVC")
        prewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
            prewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        })
```

Как можно при переходе в новый ViewController, передать информацию?

Comment: Добрый день, вопрос не очень понятен, опишите какой цели вы собираетесь достичь?

Comment: Я хочу выкинуть из памяти все VC, в которых я был. К примеру, я из ViewController1 иду в ViewController2, потом во ViewController3. Можно ли как нибудь скинуть с памяти все VC, в которых я был?

Comment: Что именно Вы хотите передать и что для этого пытались сделать? Распишите подробнее проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать метод:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

То вы вернетесь на самый корневой контроллер все остальные контроллеры из стека пропадут.

Comment: Мне необходимо скинуть с памяти все ViewController'ы, а не перейти к начальному, это возможно?